# MS SQL - JOIN only if parameter exists in stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures, param

I have a stored proc that has the following (simplified example):

```
DECLARE @id int = NULL
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ((@id IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.id = @id))
```

The purpose of this is to return all rows if @id is not provided, else return just rows matching @id.

Works as expected as long as @id is provided.  But it returns no rows is @id is null.

I thought, maybe

```
INNER JOIN table t2 ON (@id IS NULL OR ((@id IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.id = @id)))
```

might work, but if @id is null, then it seems to return unending rows (I waited 30 seconds, and it was past 1M rows.  (There are only 150 rows in table1)

I've read around, and most other examples to accomplish this seem to use dynamic SQL (which I'd rather not do), or the possibility of creating a temp table, which seems a little extreme for this kind of thing.

What are my options?  Thank you.

Comment: Use `IF @id IS NOT NULL` instead. So provide a query for the case that the parameter is `null` and one for the not-null case. That's much more efficient

Comment: you should join table1 and table2 somehow

Comment: Try writing separate queries based on parameter value!

Comment: If you show us two separate queries - first for the case when `id` is `NULL` and second for the case when `id` is not `NULL`, somebody would be able to show you how to merge them into a single query. If that is possible. Or, simply use `IF` and two separate queries as @TimSchmelter suggested. At the moment the required logic is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I am doubtful on your table joining, tried to simplified your SQL query

```
DECLARE @id int = NULL
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.id=t2.id
WHERE @id IS NULL OR t2.id = @id
```

Comment: Totally agree, the use of `t1 join t2` only makes sense if followed by an `on`-clause like this, perhaps best written as `INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.id = t2.t1_id`, but other than that: this is how it should look.

Comment: Yes for reference  column Name I am not sure about its name that's why I used `t1.id=t2.id`

Comment: This was valiant, but not the solution (so far).  By joining the way you show, the returned rows are a concatenation of t1 and t2, resulting in multiple t1 records.  In the event @id is null, I only want to retrieve 1 each of the t1 rows (as if the join never happened).

Answer (score 0):

Both table1 and table2 have one column (id) of type int in this example. It should work for other datatypes too just need to change the where clause and ISNULL function in the select accordingly as shown below ( see comments for more info on how it works )

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1]( [ID] [int] NOT NULL)  
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE2]( [ID] [int] NOT NULL)  
GO

---- For INT Datatype -----

DECLARE @id int =  1--  NULL --
SELECT Distinct A.id_t1  -- , id_t2 -- , A.ID -- , *
FROM
(
    SELECT Distinct
            t1.id as id_t1  , -- Alias the id col differently for clarity
            t2.id as id_t2  , 
            ISNULL( @id , -1 ) as ID -- Helper column to help check for NULL value passed for @id. 
    FROM        dbo.table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN  dbo.table2 t2  

) A 
WHERE (A.id_t1 = A.ID  AND A.id_t1 = A.id_t2 )  OR A.ID = -1 -- Use that Helper column A.ID to narrow down the result set to what you want


---- For Char Datatype -----
    DECLARE @id varchar(1) =  '1' --  NULL -- Uncomment to Switch between NULL and 

    SELECT Distinct A.id_t1  -- , id_t2 -- , A.ID -- Uncomment as needed for Troubleshooting purposes
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Distinct
                t1.id as id_t1  , 
                t2.id as id_t2  , 
                ISNULL( @id , 'x' ) as ID -- Helper column to help check for NULL value passed for @id. 
        FROM        dbo.table1 t1
        CROSS JOIN  dbo.table2 t2  

    ) A 
    WHERE (A.id_t1 = A.ID  AND A.id_t1 = A.id_t2 )  OR A.ID = 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a rather strange query when you have a Cartesian product of two tables.

It makes some sense if `ID` in `table2` is unique. In this case the query below will always return all rows from `table1` and either a value of the single row with the given `ID` from `table2`, or NULLs in the corresponding columns.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID1 int PRIMARY KEY, Value1 int);
INSERT INTO @Table1(ID1, Value1) VALUES
(11, 101),
(12, 102),
(13, 103),
(14, 104);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID2 int PRIMARY KEY, Value2 int);
INSERT INTO @Table2(ID2, Value2) VALUES
(21, 221),
(22, 222),
(23, 223);
```

**Query with not NULL**

```
DECLARE @id int;

SET @id = 22;
SELECT * 
FROM
    @Table1 AS T1
    LEFT JOIN @Table2 AS T2 ON T2.ID2 = @id
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

+-----+--------+-----+--------+
| ID1 | Value1 | ID2 | Value2 |
+-----+--------+-----+--------+
|  11 |    101 |  22 |    222 |
|  12 |    102 |  22 |    222 |
|  13 |    103 |  22 |    222 |
|  14 |    104 |  22 |    222 |
+-----+--------+-----+--------+
```

[image: not-null]

**Query with NULL**

```
SET @id = NULL;
SELECT * 
FROM
    @Table1 AS T1
    LEFT JOIN @Table2 AS T2 ON T2.ID2 = @id
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

+-----+--------+------+--------+
| ID1 | Value1 | ID2  | Value2 |
+-----+--------+------+--------+
|  11 |    101 | NULL | NULL   |
|  12 |    102 | NULL | NULL   |
|  13 |    103 | NULL | NULL   |
|  14 |    104 | NULL | NULL   |
+-----+--------+------+--------+
```

[image: null]

It works because `T2.ID2 = @id` returns one row from `table2` when `@id` is not NULL and returns no rows from `table2` when `@id` is NULL.

With `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` optimiser can generate optimal plan in both cases. You can see actual plans and confirm for yourself that in the second case when `@id` is NULL optimiser is smart enough to not touch `table2` at all, because it knows that `T2.ID2 = NULL` is always false.